# Average based on criteria then output

Tags: excel

I have an Excel table with the first six columns having a value of `1` or `2`. The next six columns are associated with the first six columns and have values that will need to be averaged - two averages will be computed based on whether there is a `1` or `2` value in the first six columns. Then depending on the two averages, the last six columns will need to be assigned a value equal to `H` (high average) or `L` (low average). This is difficult to explain, so here is an example:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R
1  2  2  1  2  2  1  8  8  9  8  6  8  L  L  H  L  L  H
```

Columns C and F have values equal to `1`, so columns I and L need to be averaged. Then because columns A, B, D and E have values equal to `2`, columns G, H, J and K need to be averaged. The average of the columns associated with a value of `1` (I and L) is `8.5`, and the average of the columns associated with a value of `2` (G, H, J and K) is `7.5`. Columns M-R now must be labeled with an `H` or `L` depending on whether the corresponding values from columns G-L were part of the high (H) or low (L) average. In this case, since columns I and L had the larger average, then columns O and R need to be assigned an `H`. The other columns (M, N, P and Q) will be assigned an `L` because their associated columns (G, H, J, K) had the lower average.

Comment: I don't understand how you're making these "associations."  What do columns C and F have to do with columns I and L?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider the following formula placed on the first row of Column M and then copied across to Column R:

```
=IF(AVERAGEIF($A$1:$F$1,A1,$G$1:$L$1)=MAX(AVERAGEIF($A$1:$F$1,1,$G$1:$L$1),AVERAGEIF($A$1:$F$1,2,$G$1:$L$1)),"H","L")
```

Logic is if the average of the values that correspond to either the 1 or 2 on `A1` is equal to the `MAX` of calculations between both, then this corresponds to the High number. If not it corresponds to the Low value. Note that this does not consider for when the averages are equal in which case all entries are noted as High. You can extend this by adding to the formula to check if the value is equal to the `MIN` of the same. Hope this helps. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Visual Basic, you could use this method, but it might require more columns.

```
    xx A B C D E F G H I J K L
    1  2 2 1 2 2 1 8 8 9 8 6 8
```

For cell M1 type in: =if(A1=1, G1, "")
Note that this is two regular quotes (")s in a row after the G1 term.
Copy this over to cells M1-R1.
Now cells M1-R1 should only contain data for columns marked with a 1.
Next for cell S1 type in: =average(M1:R1)
This shouldn't factor in blank cells, So you should just have the average of "1" cells.

Now copy the process for the "2" cells:
For cell T1 type in: =if(A1=2, G1, "")
Copy this to cells T1-Y1.
For cell Z1 type in: =average(T1:Y1)

Now for cell AA1 type in: =if(S1 > Z1, 1, 2)
Now AA1 will have the number that has the higher average. So if the "1" cells had a higher average, cell AA1 will be a 1, otherwise it will be a 2.
Now for cell AB1 type in =if(A1=$AA1, "H", "L")
Copy AB1 to cells AB1 through AG1 and you're done.

Cells AB1-AG1 will have your H's and L's. Note that there is one drawback to this method, apart from it being a little complex, that is that if the averages are equal, it will still print "2"s as having the higher average.


Anyways hopefully you can find a simpler method, but this one should work if you can't.